# Extracting a word between two parenthesis regex

Tags: regex

I am trying to extract word **General** using Pyspark regex from the following string:

:52.089;emailI_Pm|T(General)|20000;ml2736

How can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
re.match(r".*\((.*)\).*", ":52.089;emailI_Pm|T(General)|20000;ml2736")[1]
```

Comment: Consider using negative character classes instead of the dot: `.`